# "'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files" if a library references others libraries

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**Context**

I have an angular project containing three libraries (@packages/red, @packages/blue, @packages/colors) and one applicaton to test libraries (demo).
Theses four projects are in the projects folder.
I created these projects using @angular/cli.

@packages/colors library references @packages/blue and @packages/red libraries.

You can see the project here : https://github.com/brazilia28/my-angular-projects

**Problem**

When I build @packages/blue and @packages/red libraries, everything works.

But when I build @packages/colors library with @angular/cli :

`ng build @packages/colors`

I get a lot of errors of type :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point '@packages/colors'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: projects/packages/blue/src/public-api.ts:5:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/blue/src/lib/blue.component.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.        

5 export * from './lib/blue.component';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/blue/src/public-api.ts:6:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/blue/src/lib/blue.module.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

6 export * from './lib/blue.module';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/red/src/public-api.ts:5:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/red/src/lib/red.component.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

5 export * from './lib/red.component';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/red/src/public-api.ts:6:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/red/src/lib/red.module.ts' is not 
under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

6 export * from './lib/red.module';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/colors/src/lib/colors.module.ts:2:28 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/blue/src/public-api.ts' 
is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

2 import { BlueModule } from '@packages/blue';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/colors/src/lib/colors.module.ts:3:27 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/red/src/public-api.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

3 import { RedModule } from '@packages/red';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

An unhandled exception occurred: projects/packages/blue/src/public-api.ts:5:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/blue/src/lib/blue.component.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

5 export * from './lib/blue.component';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/blue/src/public-api.ts:6:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/blue/src/lib/blue.module.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

6 export * from './lib/blue.module';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/red/src/public-api.ts:5:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/red/src/lib/red.component.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

5 export * from './lib/red.component';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/red/src/public-api.ts:6:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/red/src/lib/red.module.ts' is not 
under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

6 export * from './lib/red.module';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/colors/src/lib/colors.module.ts:2:28 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/blue/src/public-api.ts' 
is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

2 import { BlueModule } from '@packages/blue';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/packages/colors/src/lib/colors.module.ts:3:27 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Données/Repos/my-angular-projects/projects/packages/red/src/public-api.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Données\Repos\my-angular-projects\projects\packages\colors\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

3 import { RedModule } from '@packages/red';
```

Have you any idea to solve my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Any solution so far?